# hue notebook error when use non-ascii characters in sql-editor

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I've been searching all day and I'm leaving an issue.

Please help me

```
Python : python 2.7.5
OS: Centos 7.8.2003 (Core)
Hue : 4.10.0
Hvie: 3.1.2
```

the issue was opened to resolve the error.

In the hue editor [hive sql-editor]

```
select * from subway where name = 'station'
```

it works

```
select * from subway where name = '가야역'
```

it not work

error log

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 20:40 cannot recognize input near 'like' '' '' in expression specification
```

It works normally in beeline.

```
jdbc:hive2://10.100.0.119:10000> select * from subway where name = '가야역';
INFO : Compiling command(queryId=konan_20210907155632_77ff7fb9-ede8-41f4-9855-886eb2a1cc58): select * from subway where name = '가야역'
INFO : Semantic Analysis Completed (retrial = false)
INFO : Returning Hive schema: Schema(fieldSchemas:[FieldSchema(name:subway.name, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:subway.code_list, type:string, comment:null), FieldSchema(name:subway.name_meta, type:string, comment:null)], properties:null)
INFO : Completed compiling command(queryId=konan_20210907155632_77ff7fb9-ede8-41f4-9855-886eb2a1cc58); Time taken: 0.116 seconds
INFO : Executing command(queryId=konan_20210907155632_77ff7fb9-ede8-41f4-9855-886eb2a1cc58): select * from subway where name = '가야역'
INFO : Completed executing command(queryId=konan_20210907155632_77ff7fb9-ede8-41f4-9855-886eb2a1cc58); Time taken: 0.0 seconds
INFO : OK
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| subway.name | subway.code_list | subway.name_meta |
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 가야역 | 40219 | 부산 > 가야역 |
+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

runcpserver.log

```
access INFO 10.20.2.125 konan - "POST /notebook/api/close_statement HTTP/1.1" returned in 362ms 200 67
[07/Sep/2021 15:35:05 +0900] hive_server2_lib INFO Retrying with a new session for konan because status is 4
[07/Sep/2021 15:35:05 +0900] decorators ERROR Error running execute
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/konan/bigdata/hue/desktop/libs/notebook/src/notebook/decorators.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/konan/bigdata/hue/desktop/libs/notebook/src/notebook/api.py", line 238, in execute
response = _execute_notebook(request, notebook, snippet)
File "/home/konan/bigdata/hue/desktop/libs/notebook/src/notebook/api.py", line 213, in _execute_notebook
raise ex
QueryError: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:40 cannot recognize input near 'like' '' '' in expression specification
```

hive.log

```
INFO [2915e8b9-cd89-4b57-85b2-cb24bbce6700 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-1006] ql.Driver: Compiling command(queryId=konan_20210907153530_49f60f1d-8d66-4670-a91d-382bdaf97f22):

select * from subway where name like '가�
2021-09-07T15:35:30,118 ERROR [2915e8b9-cd89-4b57-85b2-cb24bbce6700 HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-1006] ql.Driver: FAILED: ParseException line 3:40 cannot recognize input near 'like' '' '' in expression specification
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 3:40 cannot recognize input near 'like' '' '' in expression specification
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:223)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1826)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1773)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1768)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.reexec.ReExecDriver.compileAndRespond(ReExecDriver.java:126)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:197)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:260)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:247)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:541)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:527)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. edit ~/hue/apps/beeswax/gen-py/TCLIService/ttypes.py line 3922 oprot.writeString(self.statement) -> oprot.writeString(self.statement.encode('utf-8')